# Встроенные функции Lua в двоичном представлении (string.dump)

Tags: функции, lua

Сегодня я попытался представить встроенную функцию Lua в двоичном коде при помощи string.dump, однако мне выдаёт ошибку. Есть ли готовые библиотеки Lua, которые я смог бы загрузить также, как сделал бы с любой другой функцией через loadstring()? Эта возможность мне это необходима, как вспомогательный компонент защиты от подмены функций, в том числе встроенных

Comment: Либа вряд ли есть (не уверен как здесь, но на enSO просить подсказать их оффтоп, к слову). А чем плохо просто сохранить нужные функции в локальной таблице? Их там никто не тронет, только нужно копировать каждую ссылку индивуидуально. Может быть слегка муторно, но вполне возможно. Или если я неправильно понял, переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: @val, вы правильно всё поняли, однако мне важно наличие функций на физическом носителе. Взломщик без проблем сможет изменить приоритет загрузки и подменить интересующие его функции - в этом вся проблема. Возможно вопрос и правда некорректный, но мою задачу можно выполнить двумя способами: либо сделать это самый приоритет запуска неизменяемым (что более комплексно, как мне кажется), либо хранить функции в отдельных файлах, которые не дают взломщику никакого шанса

Comment: А почему взломщик не может подменить и эти файлы? Задача становится ещё проще для него... Если боитесь подмены, сделайте много lua стейтов в си, там каждый новый будет чистым. Да и чисто в теории такая библиотека невозможна - вычислить длину строки без C части, например, никак нельзя. Или взломщик всё равно подменит require/load и плакали ваши функции...

Comment: @val, спасибо, я как-то про это сразу и не подумал =D стейты действительно помогли и даже разрешили другие проблемы. Большое спасибо